# ServiceFabric SDK installation failed

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-sdk

I am trying to install ServiceFabric SDK on Azure VM (Windows Datacenter 2016) for configuring our TFS build-agent. But when I lanuch an install I got an error. I tried to re-install VS (I am using Community 2017) but it didn't help me.
Log which Microsoft Installer presented to me:

```
MSI (s) (98:F0) [11:03:39:170]: Doing action: INSTALL
MSI (s) (98:F0) [11:03:39:170]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action start 11:03:39: INSTALL.
MSI (s) (98:F0) [11:03:39:171]: Running ExecuteSequence
MSI (s) (98:F0) [11:03:39:171]: Doing action: FindRelatedProducts
MSI (s) (98:F0) [11:03:39:171]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action start 11:03:39: FindRelatedProducts.
MSI (s) (98:F0) [11:03:39:172]: Doing action: AppSearch
MSI (s) (98:F0) [11:03:39:172]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action ended 11:03:39: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 1.
Action start 11:03:39: AppSearch.
MSI (s) (98:F0) [11:03:39:173]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Signature 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (98:F0) [11:03:39:173]: Note: 1: 1402 2:     HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Service Fabric 3: 2 
MSI (s) (98:F0) [11:03:39:173]: Doing action: LaunchConditions
MSI (s) (98:F0) [11:03:39:173]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action ended 11:03:39: AppSearch. Return value 1.
Action start 11:03:39: LaunchConditions.
MSI (s) (98:F0) [11:03:39:173]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (s) (98:F0) [11:03:39:173]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT     `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1709 
MSI (s) (98:F0) [11:03:39:173]: Product: Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK     -- This product requires Service Fabric Runtime version 5.7.198.9494 to be     installed.

Action ended 11:03:39: LaunchConditions. Return value 3.
Action ended 11:03:39: INSTALL. Return value 3.
MSI (s) (98:F0) [11:03:39:175]: Note: 1: 1708 
MSI (s) (98:F0) [11:03:39:175]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (s) (98:F0) [11:03:39:175]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1708 
MSI (s) (98:F0) [11:03:39:175]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (s) (98:F0) [11:03:39:175]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1709 
MSI (s) (98:F0) [11:03:39:175]: Product: Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK     -- Installation failed.

MSI (s) (98:F0) [11:03:39:175]: Windows Installer installed the product.     Product Name: Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK. Product Version: 2.7.198.9494. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation. Installation success or error status: 1603.

MSI (s) (98:F0) [11:03:39:177]: Deferring clean up of packages/files, if any exist
MSI (s) (98:F0) [11:03:39:177]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
MSI (s) (98:E0) [11:03:39:179]: RESTART MANAGER: Session closed.
MSI (s) (98:E0) [11:03:39:179]: No System Restore sequence number for this installation.
=== Logging stopped: 9/4/2017  11:03:39 ===
MSI (s) (98:E0) [11:03:39:180]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (98:E0) [11:03:39:180]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (98:E0) [11:03:39:180]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (98:E0) [11:03:39:182]: Note: 1: 1402 2:     HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (98:E0) [11:03:39:182]: Note: 1: 1402 2:     HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (98:E0) [11:03:39:182]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (7C:18) [11:03:39:183]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (7C:18) [11:03:39:184]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
=== Verbose logging stopped: 9/4/2017  11:03:39 ===
```

Does anybody have any ideas what am I doing wrong? Thank you.

**UPD**

Here it is a log I've got after I tried to install SF Runtime.

```
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting EXE command for product 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64)'. Commandline is: 'C:\Users\kv-user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\VC11Redist_x64\ABE47E4996CF0409A794C1844F1FA8404032EDB2\vcredist_x64.exe /q /norestart'. Process Id: 2660
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install exit code for product 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64)' is '0'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install return code for product 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64)' is Success
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64) done install completed
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 2
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Number of bytes downloaded over the internet: '41922560'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Number of bytes after possible decompression: '41922560'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Moving downloaded file 'C:\Users\kv-user\AppData\Local\Temp\3\tmp9897.tmp' to: C:\Users\kv-user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsAzurePowershellGet\1F4FCC5E92035BE0907B4E83AC8661B13C0C2FA6\azure-powershell.4.3.1.msi
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Using cached file at C:\Users\kv-user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\ServiceFabricRuntime_5_7\C3ACBAF5C375D7E8834907EB208BA5EA92C507DA\MicrosoftServiceFabric.5.7.198.9494.exe instead of downloading from https://download.microsoft.com/download/2/9/E/29E129A2-5C20-46A6-83EB-A4958097DC2E/MicrosoftServiceFabric.5.7.198.9494.exe
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting MSI install for msi 'C:\Users\kv-user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsAzurePowershellGet\1F4FCC5E92035BE0907B4E83AC8661B13C0C2FA6\azure-powershell.4.3.1.msi', commandline: 'ACTION=INSTALL REBOOT=ReallySuppress'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Using cached file at C:\Users\kv-user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\ServiceFabricSDK_2_7\6ACC7553812DE4F9F48427A124789298BC44E8F4\MicrosoftServiceFabricSDK.2.7.198.msi instead of downloading from https://download.microsoft.com/download/2/9/E/29E129A2-5C20-46A6-83EB-A4958097DC2E/MicrosoftServiceFabricSDK.2.7.198.msi
DownloadManager Information: 0 : MSI install return value for product 'Microsoft Azure PowerShell' is '0'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install return code for product 'Microsoft Azure PowerShell' is Success
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Microsoft Azure PowerShell installation log: C:\Users\kv-user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\logs\install\2017-09-04T12.25.32\azure-powershell.4.3.1.txt
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product Microsoft Azure PowerShell done install completed
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 3
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting EXE command for product 'Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Runtime - 5.7.198'. Commandline is: 'C:\Windows\sysnative\cmd.exe /c wmic product where name="Microsoft Azure Service Fabric" call uninstall'. Process Id: 1256
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install exit code for product 'Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Runtime - 5.7.198' is '0'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Ignoring exit code '0' for product 'Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Runtime - 5.7.198'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting EXE command for product 'Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Runtime - 5.7.198'. Commandline is: 'C:\Users\kv-user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\ServiceFabricRuntime_5_7\C3ACBAF5C375D7E8834907EB208BA5EA92C507DA\MicrosoftServiceFabric.5.7.198.9494.exe /AcceptEULA'. Process Id: 1816
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install exit code for product 'Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Runtime - 5.7.198' is '1'
DownloadManager Error: 0 : Install return code for product 'Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Runtime - 5.7.198' is Failure
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Runtime - 5.7.198 done install completed
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 4
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Dependency failed for product 'Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK - 2.7.198'. Skipping install
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK - 2.7.198 had a dependency fail. Increasing install product to 5
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Dependency failed for product 'Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK - 2.7.198'. Skipping install
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK - 2.7.198 had a dependency fail. Increasing install product to 6
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product: VC11Redist_x64, Install Status: InstallCompleted-Success, Install Time: 00:00:01.2656949
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product: WindowsAzurePowershellGet, Install Status: InstallCompleted-Success, Install Time: 00:00:52.7939372
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product: ServiceFabricRuntime_5_7, Install Status: InstallCompleted-Failure, Install Time: 00:00:20.0043778
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product: ServiceFabricSDK_2_7, Install Status: DependencyFailed-None, Install Time: 00:00:00
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product: MicrosoftAzure-ServiceFabric-CoreSDK, Install Status: DependencyFailed-None, Install Time: 00:00:00
```

**UPD2**

That is what I've got from logs.:

```
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting EXE command for product 'Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Runtime - 5.7.198'. Commandline is: 'C:\Users\kv-user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\ServiceFabricRuntime_5_7\C3ACBAF5C375D7E8834907EB208BA5EA92C507DA\MicrosoftServiceFabric.5.7.198.9494.exe /AcceptEULA'. Process Id: 3892
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install exit code for product 'Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Runtime - 5.7.198' is '1'
DownloadManager Error: 0 : Install return code for product 'Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Runtime - 5.7.198' is Failure
```

Then I tried to do it manually using PS (and the command inside), and what I've got:

[image]

I have Undefined CurrentUser. How could this happen..?

**UPD3**

Full redeploy of VM worked for me. Unfortunately problem still a guess for me.

Comment: Ginve the error shown (`This product requires Service Fabric Runtime version 5.7.198.9494 to be     installed.`) I suggest to try [installing the runtime](http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/9/E/29E129A2-5C20-46A6-83EB-A4958097DC2E/MicrosoftServiceFabric.5.7.198.9494.exe) prior to installing the sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean redeploy for VM works for me. Unfortunately I could not give another more detailed answer or describtion on happended problem, but after full delete and totally new VM creation ServiceFabric SDK installed sucessfully.

Thank you [Shridhar R. Kulkarni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5343790/shridhar-r-kulkarni)

Comment: Actually, just running the webpicmd install over and over eventually works... looks like it's multi-treaded install, but dependencies don't complete in time for children to be install #facepalm #microsoft

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall all components *if any* installed by Service Fabric like Azure Service Fabric(runtime), Azure Service Fabric SDK and Azure Service Fabric tools for visual studio (for example in case of VS2015).

Reinstall them **in a sequence** of Azure Service Fabric(runtime), Azure Service Fabric SDK and Azure Service Fabric tools for visual studio. It worked for me.

Comment: I have visual studio 2017, it does not require ServiceFabric Tools at all because it includes them itself. But I got your point, I am trying to do it right now.

Comment: BTW, I deleted everything, VS, .net core, etc. Everything, Carl! And finally figured out that during the installation PS script returns for current user Undefined policy. Idk what to do right now... Seems like I'm doing something wrong, but what..?

Comment: Check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: Also I would suggest try installing with Web Platform Installer if you don't really need to install with powershell commands. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started

Comment: @matterai: By default, Windows blocks these scripts from running. To enable them, you must modify your PowerShell execution policy. Open PowerShell as an administrator and enter the following command: 
`Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force -Scope CurrentUser`

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately it didn't help me. Still has the same error. `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified...`. If nothing helps me I will redeploy my VM :dunno:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153618/discussion-between-shridhar-r-kulkarni-and-matterai).